# I keep getting [object Object] as the data passed instead of actual object

Tags: javascript, object

I keep getting [object Object] as the data passed into my function call. Any insights as to why? I still haven't been able to figure out even as I used JSON.stringify for my object(options).

```
the_data ='<a onclick="popup_manager.getFormPopUp('+JSON.stringify(options)+')">'+the_data+'</a>';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please checkout the [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: My first thoughts ... "passed into my function call" — you are not showing a function being called or the function that you are calling.  I assume you mean the object is `options` but you don't really say.  When calling getFormPopup you probably want to pass an object, not the JSON string representation of the object. But you're not showing enough context to decipher this, so I can't even attempt to provide an answer.

Comment: @StephenP Since they're constructing an HTML string in the `onclick` attribute, it needs to be stringifies.

Comment: @Barmar :facepalm:  
I missed that because we _never_ use on<event> handlers like this. We _always_ attach handlers programattically.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this? Your nearly-identical previous question was missing debugging details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76016265/json-stringify-doesnt-resolve-object-object-issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JSON uses `"` as its string delimiters, and this will match the `"` around the `onclick` attribute, so the attribute ends early and doesn't contain the full function call.

One way of resolving this is to swap your quotes.

```
the_data = "<a onclick='popup_manager.getFormPopUp("+JSON.stringify(options)+")'>"+the_data+'</a>';
```

but if there are any single quotes in `options` this will fail.

Instead of constructing a string, construct a DOM element.

```
let anchor = document.create_element("a");
let local_options = {...options}; // make copy of options for closure
anchor.addEventListener("click", () => popup_manager.getFormPopUp(local_options));
anchor.innerHTML = the_data;
parent_element.appendChild(anchor);
```